# Angular - $cookies is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I'm trying to user Angular cookies in my controller but for some reason it is always undefined:

```
MyApp.controller('ValidationController', ["$cookies", function($cookies) {
    debugger; //checking $cookies here return an object
    $cookies.put("test","test"); //trying to add value to the cookie here return TypeError: undefined is not a function
    alert(JSON.stringify($cookies));

}]);


var MyApp = angular.module("MyApp", [
    "ui.router",
    "ui.bootstrap",
    "oc.lazyLoad",
    "ngSanitize",
    "ngCookies"
]);
```

This is the full stack error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at new <anonymous> (CookiesController.js:6)
    at Object.e [as invoke] (angular.min.js:37)
    at $get.z.instance (angular.min.js:76)
    at angular.min.js:59
    at s (angular.min.js:7)
    at v (angular.min.js:59)
    at g (angular.min.js:52)
    at angular.min.js:51
    at angular.min.js:17
    at l.$get.l.$eval (angular.min.js:126)
```

any ideas?

Comment: which version of angular you are using?

Comment: Have you added 'ngCookies' as a dependency for your app?

Comment: @pankajparkar 1.3.10

Comment: @OrGuz yes I did.. adding that to my question

Comment: Added to my question the full stack output

Comment: i think it should be $cookieStore instead of $cookie

Comment: $cookieStore works. but according to the angular docs it is deprecated and $cookies should be used instead

Comment: @AsafNevo, can you use the non-minified version of Angular and post the error - it is more descriptive

Comment: Have you added angular-cookies.js  to your project?

Comment: @NewDev I actually decided to go with $cookieStore. do you think it matters ?

Comment: seems like $cookie doesn't have setter in angular `1.3.10` https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies while `1.4.0` does https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.6/docs/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies

Comment: @AsafNevo does this fixed? I believe you need to upgrade angular 1.4.0 to work with $cookie object

Comment: @pankajparkar yep it does! thanks! Post it as an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: @AsafNevo I added, please check it, Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like `$cookies` doesn't have setter in [**angular 1.3.10**](http://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies)  while [**angular 1.4.0**](http://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.6/docs/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies) does provided, Please refer their documents.

You could solve your problem by 2 ways.

1. If you want to stay with `angular 1.3.10` then use `$cookieStore` object instead of `$cookies`
2. Do upgrade angular to version `1.4.0.beta.6` latest version

Hope this could help you, Thanks.

Comment: ahhhhh angular changed the cookies in 1.4: "Up until Angular 1.3, $cookies exposed properties that represented the current browser cookie values. In version 1.4, this behavior has changed, and $cookies now provides a standard api of getters, setters etc." https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies